# async and await for calling couple of setTimeout in order

Tags: javascript, async-await

If I have this two variables with `setTimeout`s:

```
var printOne = setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("one!");
}, 500);

var printTwo = setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("two!");
}, 50);
```

it's just for example. What I want is, to make a function(with `async` and `await` that will call the above variables, but in order. Like this:

```
theFunction(printOne, printTwo);
// Will output:
// one! 
// two!
```

Comment: your variables finished before theFunction(printOne, printTwo),that's  bad examples

Comment: The variables store timer ids and can only be used to clear them. The timeouts are already started, there's nothing you can do after the fact. Make those *functions* that return promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish that with async functions, you need to work along with promises.

An alternative is wrapping both setTimeout calls into a function which returns a promise:

```js
var printOne = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("one!");
      resolve();
    }, 500);    
  })
}

var printTwo = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("two!");
      resolve();
    }, 50);    
  })
}

function theFunction(one, two) {
}

async function main() {
  theFunction(await printOne(), await printTwo());
}

main();
```

Comment: Thank you Ele, but why am I not able to do something like this(instead of main() ): `async theFunction(one,two){
    var a = await one();
    var b = await two();
}

theFunction(printOne, printTwo);` it says `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: actually, to make it work exactly as I wanted, I'll need to do the folowing: `async function main(a,b) {
  theFunction(await a(), await b());
}

main(printOne, printTwo);`

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that return `promise` which encapsulate `setTimeout`

```
var fnPromiseTimeout = async function(msg, time) { 
    return new Promise( (resolve) => setTimeout( () => {
      //console.log(msg);
      resolve(msg);
    }, time ) );
};
```

**Demo**

```js
var fnPromiseTimeout = async function(msg, time) { 
    return new Promise( (resolve) => setTimeout( () => {
      //console.log(msg);
      resolve(msg);
    }, time ) );
};

async function f1(timer1, timer2)
{
  console.log("start");
  var a = await timer1;
  console.log(a);
  var b = await timer2;
  console.log(b);
  console.log("end");
}
f1(fnPromiseTimeout("one", 500), fnPromiseTimeout("two", 500));
```